# Which way is better for sending functions references to react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference, components

I'm trying to send function reference to imported component. So it's better I use ref attribute or props ?

I want to find an optimum and standard method.

```js
<MyComponent ref="ListView" />
```

Or this method:

```js
<MyComponent show="this.showModal" hide="this.hideModal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be an effect if you pass functions as a string (like `"this.showModal"`).

Pass them down in curly braces:

```
<MyComponent show={this.showModal} hide={this.hideModal} />
```

Refs purpose is to manipulate DOM directly, not to pass something to the component. For example, you may want to manipulate DOM with jQuery

Comment: ok, but how is when I have a lot of methods ? I should use ref ?

Comment: Mohammad, I've written down the update regarding refs. Just pass a lot of methods.

Comment: @Mohammad you can keep track of your props which methods are being passed as props. we use refs  for DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I understood your question, if you have a lot of method you can use ...props but also you can pass props as separated methods.

I think you're referring to the differences between controlled and uncontrolled components :
uncontrolled-
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
controlled-
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

The answer for that is depending on your component "logic", if you want to controll it by the DOM(using refs) or by the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use refs for event handling it is preferable to pass handlers as props to child component using **JSX** sytax with `{}` braces.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send **eventhandler** to **child** component from **parent** if i understand your question correctly?

**parent.js**

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

  handler = () => {
     console.log("handler click">
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Child handler={this.handler} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

**child.js**

```
const Child = ({ handler }) => (
  <Button onClick={handler} />
)
```

Comment: Ok, but how I should write the handler method ? I should pass a class ? for example I have to many function for: hide, show, get api data, delete, update etc.

Comment: Can you please provide clear workflow of hide, show, get api data, delete, update? Illustration might help